# Schedule deployment change set

Tags: schedulebatch, change-set, scheduled-job, schedule

I have the need to make a changeset once a week from develpment enviroment to test enviroment. Is it possible to schedule this action?
I would like to create a batch job to do this but I can't find anything about that. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to move data or metadata?

Comment: I'm trying to move all that is changed during the week

Comment: Not possible with the actual Change Sets themselves but if you use the Force Migration tool it is possible to schedule jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Force.com Migration Tool (ant) and write a small script to do this.

The steps would be:

1. ant retrieve from the source org
2. ant deploy to the target org

You would need somewhere to run this, such as Jenkins or Travis or anywhere that allowed you to run a recurring task.

The issue you are likely to encounter is what kind of metadata you want to move and what clashes will occur. Think of things like Assignment Rules with specific users mentioned that don't exist in the target or Profiles that refer to packages that exist in one org but not the other.

There are commercial offerings, like the company I run, which will do this for you. Check out [Gearset](https://gearset.com) if you want to move the burden of this process to somebody else, but there are others that will do it and you can roll it yourself using Jenkins and ant

Comment: Ok thank you! I

Comment: Good on you disclosing your affiliation and laying out alternatives.